# Use property from child in super class

Tags: java, arrays, oop

In my child class I got something like:

```
protected String[] columns = {"column1", "column2"};
```

While in my parent class I have a method that will store those in a HashMap.

```
public HashMap<Integer, String> getColumns() {
    HashMap<Integer, String> columnsMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
        columnsMap.put(i + 1, this.columns[i]);
    }
    return columnsMap;
}
```

But as it seems, I cant simply use the `String[] columns` property on my sub class.
How would I be able to do this?

Comment: I believe your choices are use a Singleton, or a Multiton, or make it an abstract method that returns `String[]` in the parent and return the `String[]` from the child.

Comment: How will you access this result (values from sub class) if you are making Super class as Abstract. How do you call getColumns() method. Just want to know the scenario where this can be useful. (Assuming you are going with the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an abstract method which will retrieve an array of String containing column names and then, define it in your child class.

In the parent :

```
protected abstract String[] getColumnNames();

public HashMap<Integer, String> getColumns() {
    HashMap<Integer, String> columnsMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] columns = this.getColumnNames(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
         columnsMap.put(i + 1, columns[i]);
    }
return columnsMap;
```

}

In the child :

```
protected String getColumnNames()
{
     return new String[] {"column1", "column2"};
}
```

Comment: Add some Explanation and remove the duplicate signature `getColumns()` then it's worth +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to access the `String[]` defined at the sub class from the method in parent class, what you could do is to access it via a method like `getColumnNames()`. Sub class needs to override this method and return the `String[]` defined as a variable.

Note that unlike method overriding declaring another field with the same name in subclass doesnot amount to overriding. The superclass variable value stays unchanged, subclass field becomes another field. Fields are never overridden only methods are overridden.

Comment: But if I implement **public abstract String[] getColumns();** in my parent, I have to rename my current **getColumns()** method, right?

Comment: Yes, I just implemented the getColumnNames() abstract method before u editted it. Thanks tho!

Comment: I edited my answer, idea is to have a method to return the String[], you could call it 'getColumnNames()' parent class can call this method.